# How to dynamically open a collapsed grid?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a grid that is initialized in the 'collapsed' state when it is first loaded. I want to have the grid open when an element outside of the grid is clicked. I tried to find a built in jqGrid method that would allow me to do this but with no luck.

My best attempt is to trigger a click event on the open/close button.

```
$('#gridwrapper').find('.HeaderButton').click()
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue using this:

```
$('.ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close').click();
```

I've used `jqGrid  4.6.0`.

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/12808/)